# Keep having "530 Login incorrect" for virtual users

Tags: vsftpd

Following the documentation and what are on the Internet, I installed `libpam-pwdfile` and here are my configurations:

```
# /etc/vsftpd.conf
listen_ipv6=YES
listen_port=<port>
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsftpd
nopriv_user=vsftpd
hide_ids=YES
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/vsftpd/$USER
pam_service_name=vsftpd
utf8_filesystem=YES
```

and

```
# /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd.passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

and

```
$ useradd --home /home/vsftpd --gid <group> -m --shell /bin/false vsftpd
$ htpasswd -c -b /etc/vsftpd.passwd <virtual user> $(openssl passwd -1 -noverify <password>)
```

However when I connect to the FTP with `<virtual user>:<password>`, I constantly get

```
USER <virtual user>
530 Login incorrect.
```

So what am I missing?

**Update**: I can log in normally if vsftpd is configured to use db (with `db_load` and `pam_userdb.so`) but not passwd file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the `-p` option when invoking `htpasswd`

this should work:

```
htpasswd -c -p -b /etc/vsftpd.passwd <virtual user> $(openssl passwd -1 -noverify <password>)
```

see here for reference: [vsftpd will not accept passwords encrypted with MD5](https://serverfault.com/a/637938/557256)